# JavaScript Clock won't display correctly

Tags: javascript, html, clock

I've been teaching myself JavaScript and i'm still fairly new, i've tried to make a clock feature to add to my site, however, I can't see to get it to display, this is my full code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function tick() {
        var hours, minutes, seconds, ap;
        var intHours, intMinutes, intSeconds;
        var today;

        today = new Date();

        intHours = today.getHours();
        intMinutes = today.getMinutes();
        intSeconds = today.getSeconds();

        if (intHours == 0) {
            hours = "12:";
            ap = "Midnight";
        } else if (intHours < 12) {
            hours = intHours + ":";
            ap = "a.m";
        } else if (intHours == 12) {
            hours = "12:";
            ap = "noon";
        } else {
            intHours = intHours - 12
            hours = intHours + ":";
            ap = "p.m.";
        }
        if (intMinutes < 10) {
            minutes = "0" + intMinutes + ":";
        } else {
            minutes = intMinutes + ":";
        }
        if (intSeconds < 10) {
            seconds = "0" + intSeconds + " ";
        } else {
            seconds = intSeconds + " ";
        }
        timeString = hours + minutes + seconds + ap;

        Clock.innerHTML = timeString;

        window.setTimeout("tick();", 100);
    }

    //--></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="Clock" align="center" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10px; color:#000000"></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

As I said, I run it and as far as I can see, it should run fine, as I said i'm a bit new, so maybe someone could help me out.

Thanks again people.

EDIT: Before anyone says, I am fully aware that there are premade working examples of this kind of thing, such as jQuery clocks etc, but I wanted to make one myself from scratch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not starting, mainly because you need to call the function at least once initially:

```
tick();
```

---

Where ever you are learning HTML and JavaScript from, **stop learning from there immediately**; the code habits and methods you are learning are very, very poor and outdated.

Problems include:

- not having a DOCTYPE: `<!DOCTYPE html>`
- accessing `div#Clock` as a global variable `Clock`, which is deprecated, and should be `document.getElementById('Clock');`
- using a string to `setTimeout`, when it should really be `setTimeout(tick, 100);`
- using the deprecated `align` attribute, when you should use `text-align: center;` in CSS
- using the 'old-browser' JavaScript comment-out trick
- using inline CSS via the `style` attribute, which constitutes poor separation of presentation and content

Comment: I forgot about DOCTYPE, this wasn't really to be published anywhere etc, more just a play, but thanks for that :) I've altered the clock selectors as mentioned but its still not displaying :\

Comment: Thanks man! I put window.onload = tick(); and its working beautiful, thanks again man!

Comment: Not a problem. It should really be `window.onload = tick;` without the parentheses.

Comment: I would also say that inline CSS is deprecated, as well as `// -->` (@Aaron you didn't start with that old-browser comment anyway).

Comment: Whether or not inline styling is technically deprecated is debatable, but I agree that it is bad separation of presentation and content, and therefore, bad practice. Also, the 'old-browser' comment trick is definitely bad. I'll edit my answer to include those; thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to run your function tick() somewhere. It doesn't do anything if you only define it. In the body `onLoad` event for example.

Second, your element should be properly set in a var. You should get the element by id:

```
var Clock = document.getElementById('Clock');
```

Comment: Upvoted as this is also right, the other guy just got there first, thanks man.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your last two lines from

```
    window.setTimeout("tick();", 100);
}
```

to

```
}    
window.setInterval(tick, 1000);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/naveen/3PQ8B/1/

Update: missed the `document.getElementById` part :)

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function startTime()
{
var today=new Date();
var h=today.getHours();
var m=today.getMinutes();
var s=today.getSeconds();
// add a zero in front of numbers<10
m=checkTime(m);
s=checkTime(s);
document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML=h+":"+m+":"+s;
t=setTimeout('startTime()',500);
}

function checkTime(i)
{
if (i<10)
  {
  i="0" + i;
  }
return i;
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="startTime()">
<div id="txt"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not very helpful as it is simply a rewrite but does not point out the faults in the original poster's code.